# what type of printer to print QR code and how to print qr code with php?

Tags: php, qr-code, barcode, barcode-printing

I am creating qrcode generator with php. the application is ready and able to create qr code image successfully. I am planning to buy barcode printer but I am not sure if all barcode printer can print qr code. I have questions regarding this issues.

1. is there any specific printer to print qr code or any type of barcode printer can print qr code?
2. do i need to use "printer own programming language" to print qr code? ( i read this [blog](https://blog.lysender.com/2009/08/barcode-printing-via-php/), she says she need to use "printer own programming language" to print barcode.

Comment: If you have already built the QR code as a graphic, why do you need a special printer to print it? If you are going to use a special printer that prints QR code, you will have to send it data in the format that it is expecting. Not all barcode printers support QR code, but the ones that do, have their own formatting language. You send them the data and some metadata to control the symbology.

Comment: personally i think general printer is good enough but my friend insists to use barcode printer instead :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use a "Barcode Printer" you don't need to build your own barcode image. You can simply send the printer commands to print the type of barcode you want, QRcode or others, and send the data. The printer is taking care of the formatting.

As an example, Zebra Technologies' barcode printers use [ZPL (Zebra Printing Language)](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) and you can use the `^BQ` command to print a QRcode.

The most critical piece is how you handle the drivers and the connection between the browser and the printer.

Having the printer attached to the PC and controlled by a printer driver may not be the best solution, depending how many time you need to replicate the setup.

You may want to investigate solutions like:

1. [Browser Print:](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/browser-print.html) you've a JavaScript API to talk with the printer directly.
2. [Cloud Connect:](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/cloud-connect.html) the printer is connected directly to the server with a secure communication and is the server sending commands to the printer.

*Disclaimer:* I work for Zebra Technologies, similar solutions may exist for other printers brand, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: "you don't need to build your own barcode image", what if i want to attach image in the centre of the qrcode?

Comment: You can print the image. You can use the printer language to do the layout or a label using a WYSIWYG label designer. Sometimes the image needs to be in a specific format to be handled by the printer. But that is printer specific.